# Box Blur Convolution Outputting Same Result After Changing Kernel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, convolution, blur

I am new to Matlab and I am trying to use a box blur on a grayscale image. When I change the values in the kernel I use, I do not see any difference in the blurred images I get.

```
box_filter = 1/9 * [1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1];

box_blur_grey = mat2gray(conv2(box_filter, grey));

figure, imshow(box_blur_grey);
```

If, for example, I do `box_filter = 1/18 * [1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1];`, I do not see any change in box_blur_grey. Can anybody please help me find out why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: You should see a difference: one output image has values twice as large as the other output image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Except that `mat2gray` scales the matrix.

Comment: @beaker Didn’t know that. So OP wouldn’t see the difference of the convolution output.